# Selenium RC and Python 2 remote control

Tags: python, selenium

I have mounted a server with Selenium RC, I do the test and export it to Python 2 remote control. From my nagios server I run selenium.py but the test fails because you can not change the window.

The test is as follows: I open a url, I click on a button that opens another window and in that window I click on another button that opens another window. The problem is that the test stops searching for the second window button because it does not locate it because it stays in the first window.

This is the export code of Selenium IDE in python 2 remote control

Comment: Where's your code?